# Multivariate multiple input batch data regression

Tags: neural-network, regression, predictive-modeling

So, in general, my question is how to approach modeling with this kind of data.

I'll try to explain the challenge and some of my thought process.

### Challenge

I have batches of cars sold. One batch may contain 3 cars, other may contain 10. So the number of cars is not fixed.

Each car has its own characteristic. Let's say I have fixed number of cars characteristics.

**Example**:

| CarName | fueltype | aspiration | door number | carbody | drivewheel | cylindernumber | enginesize | horsepower |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| audi fox | gas | std | two | sedan | fwd | five | 136 | 110 |
| audi 100ls | gas | std | four | sedan | fwd | five | 136 | 110 |
| audi 5000 | gas | std | four | wagon | fwd | five | 136 | 110 |
| audi 4000 | gas | turbo | four | sedan | fwd | five | 131 | 140 |
| audi 5s | gas | turbo | two | hatchback | 4wd | five | 131 | 160 |
| bmw 320i | gas | std | two | sedan | rwd | four | 108 | 101 |
| bmw 320i | gas | std | four | sedan | rwd | four | 108 | 101 |

So this is a 7 cars batch, for which I know the price. However, I do not know the price of each car.

### Question

My question would be, is there a way to model price prediction of batches of variable number of cars in them? Having a way to interpret what influenced the price would be even better. Having a way to predict each car's price would be great.

In a sense this is like trying to compress multiple observations into "aggregated" one, but with keeping as much info of each original observation in mind when doing a prediction.

### Thought process

Now, my thought process was to do component analysis, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach since latent vector space will be different for each batch, given the variable number of observations in it.

Other approach that I was thinking is using LSTM and feeding it with rows in a sequence. At the end I would expect a price prediction. I'm not expert in neural networks, but vaguely this makes sense and is somehow similar to how LSTM is used for parsing sentences. One big difference is that order of words in sentence makes a difference, but in my case it shouldn't.

Any insight, remark or discussion would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: If you can model each car as a vector embedding, then you can model the batch of cars as the sum or average of its constituent "car vectors". This is analogous to word embedding models. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure about the logistics of training supervised "car vectors", versus obtaining them through unsupervised means beforehand, nor have I actually used this technique for things _other than_ natural language.

Comment: An entirely different option is to use a multilevel/hierarchical model (Bayesian or otherwise), wherein you generate batch-wise predictions by computing individual predictions and taking the batch-wise sum. This lets you build a _probabilistic_ model, whereas the "car embedding" approach is non-probabilistic but should be able to learn a more-complicated nonlinear relationship between car features and sale prices.

Comment: @shadowtalker Well apart from the plain and simple encoding in N dimensional vector space, I'm not quite sure how it should be done. This approach seems doable, but I'm not sure what kind of vector arithmetic would capture underlying nature of rows for each batch. With NLP and word embedding, vectors capture wider context of the word and than it makes sense to sum them or subtract them.

Comment: That's a good point. In this case there isn't any "context" for a car: a car is just a vector of its features. But I'm not sure how you'd go about obtaining unsupervised "car vectors"; maybe some kind of dimension reduction? I don't know of any techniques for autoencoders on "heterogeneous" data, but something like that might exist too. You could actually try the mean of the original features, and then divide the label by batch size, so that your features are "average car within batch" and your labels are "average cost per car within batch".

Comment: I was initially thinking about some kind of dimensionality reduction but I'm not sure what to do even if I manage it by using any of autoencoders/pca/etc. Regarding averaging, I had that in mind, but that hides the nature of batch and there is also a question averaging categorical features.

Comment: For future reference, I think that GNN approach could lead to a resolution of this challenge. It leaves a lot of space for choosing how to form a problem, but at least number of observations can vary from group to group (graph connections between observations in same group), and by message passing each of observations could end up with price prediction, as well as whole graph.